# pip в pycharm на windows10

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pip

Я ввожу в терминале Pycharm pip install, терминал говорит, что pip уже установлен в anaconda. Как сделать так, чтобы пользоваться в pycharm pip'ом?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, какую команду вы даете (`pip install` без указания имени пакета/пути не делает ничего, а просто пишет, что нужно указать одну или несколько зависимостей), и что получаете в ответ. Насколько я помню, anaconda обычно пишет, что у нее есть conda, а pip вам не нужен (в деталях могу ошибаться, снес анаконду довольно давно).

Comment: @insolor: conda позволяет свой pip установить. Вероятно стоит в обратном направлении идти: настроить PyCharm на использование python и соответственно pip от conda. С PyCharm не работаю, так что не знаю насколько это разумно.

Comment: @jfs, Pycharm позволяет устанавливать пакеты без использования командной строки. Если для проекта будет настроено использование интерпретатора из anaconda, то и pip будет использоваться оттуда же. А вот если установлено несколько версий Python (или используется venv), то не факт, что при запуске pip из командной строки, будет запущен именно тот pip, который должен использоваться для данного проекта. В любом случае, нужно более детальное описание проблемы.